# Select from a list in a parameter value

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to have a dropdown with subject areas for a school report. The problem I am running into is that in my database, the subjects are grouped by grade and subject instead of just subject. So when I look at gt.standardid in (@SubjectArea) for "Literacy" the standard ids for literacy are (54,61,68,75,88,235) one for each grade level, but I want to have it show me all of them as Literacy. In my parameter "@subjectArea" I have specific values I want to add for each subject area, so for the Label of "Literacy" I want it to select the StandardIds (54,61,68,75,88,235). I am not sure how to accomplish this.

```
Select 
 CS.subjectArea 
,CS.Name As Group_Name
,GT.Abbreviation
,GT.Name
,GT.standardID
From GradingTask as GT
inner join CurriculumStandard CS 
on GT.Standardid = CS.standardid
where GT.ARCHIVED = 0
and GT.standardid in (@SubjectArea)
ORDER BY GT.seq
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try a cascading parameter approach.

You can have the first parameter be a pre-defined list:
[image: SubjectList_General]

[image: SubjectList_AvailabileValues]

The specific values are not important, but will be used in the next step.

Ideally your IDs would be in a table already, but if not you can use something like this:

```
declare @SubjectIDs as table
(
    [SubjectName] nvarchar(50),
    [SubjectID] int
);
insert into @SubjectIDs
(
    [SubjectName],
    [SubjectID]
)
values
('Literacy', 54),
('Literacy', 61),
('Literacy', 68),
('Literacy', 75),
('Literacy', 88),
('Literacy', 23);

select
    SubjectID
from @SubjectIDs
where SubjectName in (@SubjectList);
```

Make this into a data set. I'm going to call it `DS_SubjectIDs`.
[image: DS_SubjectIDs]

Make a new hidden or internal parameter called SubjectIDs:
[image: SubjectIDs_General]

Set it to get its values from the DS_SubjectIDs query:
[image: SubjectIDs_AvailableValues]

You can now use the parameter for SubjectIDs in your final query.